# How to allow only use the english language to fill the form fields in magento 2

Tags: forms, magento2.3.1, registration

In Magento 2,

We have a registration form with some customization, But some attackers tried to enter the anonymous values inside the text fields that anonymous values are in the different languages.

For example, the first name field accepts the following value

**уверенная в себе**

How do I prevent my site from this type of spammers? Please provide the assistance

Comment: You can restrict user to enter character other then English by using Javascript. please visit : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144167/only-allow-english-characters-and-numbers-for-text-input

Comment: Can you share your form code? So I can help you put validation based on that, as I don't know how you coded for the form and your fields.